# Extjs Multi Slider

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I am Using MutliSlider in My Application..

Is it possible to know which direction we are moving slider (left to right or right to left)

I tried many ways to find slider movement.. please suggest me solution is very appreciaeble

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer of using thumb value which is index of slider
if(thumb.index==0) then left slider bar moved
else it is right